# How to write this query with ActiveRecord or Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid

Both of the interfaces for Mongoid and ActiveRecord are similar enough so I think either or will work. I need a query to meet the following criteria.

I need to know the number of days a particular type of cereal has been eaten in the last 10 days. The cereal can be eaten 10 times in one day, but I only need to know that the day has had at least 1 time that the cereal was eaten. So if today is 11th, and a user has eaten Fruity Pebbles 2 times on the 5th, 10 times on the 7th, and once on the 8th, the answer is still 3.

How does one perform a query similar to that with ActiveRecord or Mongoid? Assume the base class is 'Cereal' and there is a field named 'type'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood. `Cereal.where(:last_eaten.gt => Date.today - 10.day)` or something like that in mongoid ? I'm going with my guts here, might not be completely correct

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without a proper sample of your model.

This could work if your model fits what I have in mind (similar to Katen's answer):

```
Cereal.where("date > ?", Date.today - 10.days).select("distinct(date)").count
```

You might have to tweak it a bit, but that's essentially what you have to do.

Comment: The problem here is that Thu Jan 12 22:13:24 UTC 2012 is not distinct when compared to Thu Jan 12 22:15:35 UTC 2012. It has to be distinct by day.

Comment: If date is a date than it's fine, but if it's a datetime you just need to convert the value in the distinct SQL method.